# select-string with multiple patterns, one line output

Tags: powershell

I am extracting info from a large text file. When I do this using the code below all my patterns go to separate lines. I would like them to output to one.

```
get-content c:\dev\test\data.txt | Select-String "First:","Last:" | Add-Content c:\dev\test\output.txt
```

This currently gives me:

> John
>   Doe
>   Mary
>   Smith

I would like:

> John Doe
>   Mary Smith

Comment: That did not post correctly, sorry. Example one outputs each word on a separate line. I would like it to be First Last on one line then break.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jeroen!!!

Comment: No problem. Note that there's a preview when editing/posting, I highly suggest using it because most views/votes tend to come right after initially posting, so that'll get you best results/answers.

Comment: Can you add a small sample from the text file you're reading?

Comment: I doubt that `Select-String "First:","Last:"` gives you the output, that you describe, as the strings in your output neither contain "First:" nor "Last:".

Comment: Please provide sample input that you expect to turn into your sample output.

Comment: Sorry Manuel, I was being too generic. My bad. The output is as described but with the First: and Last: labels included. The file has a bunch of info with "First: John" on one line and "Last: Doe" on the next line. I want to output them to the same line "First: John Last: Doe"

Comment: Please edit your question with a few lines of the data. You can genericize any user specific information if you are worried about privacy but seeing what you want to parse will help immensely with deciding how to actually parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$text = @"
First: John
Last: Doe
lasld

First: Mary
dasd
Last: Smith
"@

$text | Select-String '(?s)First:\s+(\w+).*?Last:\s+(\w+)' -AllMatches |
ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
ForEach-Object { "$($_.Groups[1].Value) $($_.Groups[2].Value)" }
```

Output:

```
John Doe
Mary Smith
```

It requires the input as a single multi-line string, so you would need to use `$text = Get-Content "c:\dev\test\data.txt" -Raw` or `$text = (Get-Content "c:\dev\test\data.txt") -join [environment]::NewLine`

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/bD2oU3/1

**Update:** I realized that some people may have middlenames, so as long as the line ends with the name like the samples, you could use the regex below to include more than the first word after "First:" and "Last:". It also removes trailing whitespace on the line

```
$text = @"
First: John Lala     
Last: Doe
lasld

First: Mary
dasd
Last: Smith Test
"@

$text | Select-String '(?ms)First:\s+(.*?)\s{0,}$.*?Last:\s+(.*?)\s{0,}$' -AllMatches |
ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
ForEach-Object { "$($_.Groups[1].Value) $($_.Groups[2].Value)" }

John Lala Doe
Mary Smith Test
```

Comment: v2 added to support middlenames and etc.